# Media Player, parar som antes de tocar outro

Tags: java, android

Bom dia, eu estou com um projeto para que quando um botão seja apertado ele execute um som pre determinado
porem se eu aperto um botão dps do outro, fica os dois sons tocando, eu tentei por um if para caso algo esteja tocando ele pause e começe o outro
porem ele crasha o app ao tentar verificar se não tiver nada tocando
se alguém souber um jeito de fazer com que 2 sons não se reproduzam ao mesmo tempo Eu fico muito grato :D

```
    public void nelson (View view) {
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.nelson);
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();
                mp = null;
            }
        });
        mp.start();

}
```

Comment: Poste o código dos dois botões, será mais fácil dar uma resposta.

Comment: pronto coloquei

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de criar um MediaPlayer destrua o anterior, caso exista algum.

```
//Use sempre a mesma variável para guardar o objecto MediaPlayer
private MediaPlayer mp = null;

public void nelson (View view) {

    //Destrói o MediaPlayer caso haja algum criado.
    releasePlayer();
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.nelson);
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                //Destrói o MediaPlayer
                releasePlayer();
            }
        });
        mp.start();

}

private void releasePlayer() {
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }
}
```